# Javascript / How does the function know about nature of value, index and self?

Tags: javascript

I have tried to understand this function :

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }
  
  var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
  var unique = a.filter(onlyUnique); // returns ['a',1,2,'1']
```

I wonder how onlyUnique knows about **value, index and self** being indeed the value, the index, and the array ? Is this related to the filter ?

Comment: Are you asking how does `filter` method works ?

Comment: Probably you should check the polyfill for `filter` method to get better understanding.

Comment: @AbhaySrivastav Why not just see the [documentation for filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @phuzi Yeah, that should also work.

Comment: When a function is called, the arguments are passed values in order. The names the function uses for them internally can be anything you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) filter function can take multiple arguments. The rest is purely how javascript functions work.

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
  
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var unique = a.filter(onlyUnique); // returns ['a',1,2,'1']
```

is simply equivalent to:

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
  
var a = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];
var unique = a.filter((value, index, self) => onlyUnique(value, index, self)); // returns ['a',1,2,'1']
```